# Eclipse debug toolbar is not active

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I started Eclipse today and, when i started to debug, application stopped at the break point as it should have, but the debug toolbar was not active, and there was no possibility to step over or do anything. Picture bellow - [image]

Answer (score 1):

Can you check the log, for any possible exceptions. Any runtime exception might also be stopping the thread.

Comment: In the picture I posted above, you can see that my toolbar is shown.

Answer (score 0):

You can right click on your debug perspective (in the right upper corner, the one with the bug on it) and click on reset. This will reset the debug perspective to it's defaults.

Comment: Are you sure that this does anything except restore the debug perspective to its default state?

Comment: Yes it resets the perspective of the eclipse ide. It doesnt change any run or debug configurations.